# String number into number in PHP

Tags: php, string, numbers

Say I have a string like John01Lima

is there any way to pull out the two numbers and have them as numbers that can be incremented with $number++ ?

Comment: What if there are two numbers in the String? `John01Lima2` is this never possible? Or should the 2nd number be dropped?

Comment: You can pull a number out of a string pretty easily using [RegEx](http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html).

Comment: I think the answer really depends on how specific you can guarantee the format of the string to be.  If you know that it's always going to be similar to the example you gave, then yes, it's doable.

Comment: The string will always be like this YYYYMMDD00.pdf where YYYYMMDD is the date, and 00 are the numbers I need to access and increment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your format will always be 'YYYYMMDD00.pdf' I would do this little function:

```
function increment_filename($incoming_string)
{
    // The RegEx to Match
    $pattern = "/[0-9]{2}(?=\.pdf$)/i";
    // Find where it matches
    preg_match($pattern, $incoming_string, $matches);
    // Replace and return the match incremented
    return preg_replace($pattern, $matches[0] + 1, $incoming_string);
}
```

If you need it to match any file extension, this should work:

```
function increment_filename($incoming_string)
{
    // The RegEx to Match
    $pattern = "/[0-9]{2}(?=\.[a-z]+$)/i";
    // Find where it matches
    preg_match($pattern, $incoming_string, $matches);
    // Replace and return the match incremented
    return preg_replace($pattern, $matches[0] + 1, $incoming_string);
}
```

Hope that helps, was awesome practice to hone my RegEx skills. :)

Comment: Actually it should probably have a conditional statement on the preg_match too now that I think about it. Incase the string happens not to match so we get no errors from trying to access the match array.